# Trying to make an anchor open with javascript and python

Tags: javascript, python, html

First of all, sorry for any mistakes, I'm an extreme novice coder.

What I'm trying to do is open a link on a page (which is html generated by python), have it open in another window to an anchor. This anchor is a reversedisplay javascript, which means that I want to open the contents of where the anchor is.

The initial python/html link is as follows:

```
print "/>TEXT HERE<a value=\"mg-auto\" onClick=\"Open('mg-auto')\" href=\"http://LINKHERE/#mg-auto\" target=\"_blank\"><font title=\"mg-auto\" >(<span class=\"tooltip\">?</span>)</font></a>"
```

which you would click to lead to this:

```
<a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('mg-auto')">mg-auto</a>
<div id="mg-auto" style="display:none;">
TEXT HERE 
<hr />
</div>
```

The javascript function to open the reverse display is this:

```
function Open(d) {
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
```

I have implemented this function in both the html and the python.

However, for some reason the anchor won't work at all. I fiddled around and discovered that a header + id like so:

```
<h3 id="IDNAME"></h3>
```

will make a valid anchor, but the div + id like I have will not.However, I can't combine a header and the javascript function without breaking the html.

Does anyone know of a way to make an anchor work? I guess my biggest problem is no matter how I try to implement the id, when I try to link to the anchor it will not recognize the '#IDNAME'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cquora/v5d0wtce/7/    Does that help? I haven't used jsfiddle before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, you want someone clicking on the '(?)' to get a new window where the div that is `display="none"` to start with gets `display="block"`.

Putting '#mg-auto' after the link (a *fragment* or *hash*) will take you to the element with that id attribute when the page loads (it will jump-scroll to it if it is off screen). But the problem is that the `onClick="Open('mg-auto')"` will get run *before* you follow the link, not after the new page loads in a new window. So in the new window the div still has `display="none"`.

To run something when a page loads you can use the `window.onload` event, so all you then need is the hash. Check the code below.

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Check if hash exists
  if(window.location.hash) {
    // Remove the "#" from the hash
    hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    // Display element with id == hash
    document.getElementById(hash).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

That code will run when everything on the page has been loaded.

PS: You can essentially put an id on any element (including div and headings) and have the hash of you url take you to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I would not have thought that the order of opening different functions would be the problem; I will be sure to remember the order functions are called after a page load the next time I work on html and javascript :)